# SharePoint Foundation 2013 cannot be installed on Windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I get this error when i try to install SharePoint extensions for team foundation server 2013 on windows server 2012 r2.

SharePoint Foundation 2013 cannot be installed on Windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012 R2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Service Pack 1 for SharePoint is released, this will be fixed. Until then, this is what it is. See:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2891274

> Currently, Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 is not supported for installation on computers running the Windows Server 2012 R2 operating system. 
>   Installing SharePoint Server 2013 on a computer that is running Windows Server 2012 R2 could lead to unexpected behavior, therefore, Microsoft does not support SharePoint Server 2013 in Windows Server 2012 R2.
>
> SharePoint Server 2013 with Service Pack 1 and SharePoint Foundation 2013 with Service Pack 1 will offer support for Windows Server 2012 R2. The release date for Service Pack 1 for SharePoint Server 2013 and SharePoint Foundation 2013 is to be determined. This article will be updated as more information becomes available.

---

Last week Microsoft released Service Pack 1 for SharePoint 2013. To install on Windows 2012R2 you can download the newly released ISO from MSDN subscriptions which includes SP1:

> ### SharePoint Server 2013 with SP1 (x64) - DVD (English)
>
> ISO English Release Date: 2/28/2014
>
> Download 2692 MB
>
> For more information, please visit: [Office 2013 Service Pack 1](http://blogs.technet.com/b/office_sustained_engineering/archive/2014/02/25/announcing-the-release-of-service-pack-1-for-office-2013-and-sharepoint-2013.aspx).
>
> **File Name**: en_sharepoint_server_2013_with_sp1_x64_dvd_3823428.iso
>
> **Languages**: English
>
> **SHA1**: 9C29CF62E151D362FB02FBF07AEB0440C52DF555
>
> **Permalinks**: [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/?FileId=57191#FileId=57191) [Download](http://msdn.microsoft.com/subscriptions/json/GetDownloadRequest?brand=MSDN&locale=en-us&fileId=57191&activexDisabled=false&akamaiDL=false) [Direct Download](http://msdn.microsoft.com/subscriptions/json/GetDownloadRequest?brand=MSDN&locale=en-us&fileId=57191&activexDisabled=true&akamaiDL=false)
>
> **Available to these Subscription Levels**:
>       VS Premium with MSDN (Retail)
>       VS Premium with MSDN (VL)
>       VS Ultimate with MSDN (MPN)
>       VS Ultimate with MSDN (NFR FTE)
>       VS Ultimate with MSDN (Retail)
>       VS Ultimate with MSDN (VL)
>       BizSpark
>       BizSpark Admin
>       DreamSpark Premium
>       MCT Developer Software & Services
>       MCT Software & Services
>       MSDN Platforms
>       VS Premium with MSDN (MPN)

---

Microsoft has also released [SharePoint Foundation 2013 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42002) but no word yet as to how you can install that onto Windows Server 2012r2. I suspect that an updated installer will be released (soon) that includes SP1.

Comment: ok.. service pack 1 was released now, but how to install service pack before of sharepoint?

Comment: @devi You have to install the SharePoint version that comes with SP1 i.e. the one posted above. You cannot install SharePoint 2013 on Windows Server 2012 R2 and then install SP1 separately.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you install SharePoint 2013 with SP1, the TFS 2013 extensions are a separate product, so SP1 does not address the entire issue.

But as of today, there is a solution...you can use the new TFS 2013.2 update to resolve this issue.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/04/02/tfs-2013-2-update-2-released.aspx

"The TFS 2013.2 SharePoint extensions are now unblocked on Windows 2012 R2"

Comment: I've got Update 2 installed, but I still get the message "SharePoint Foundation 2013 cannot be installed on Windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012 R2".

Comment: I have the same message, it seems the SharePoint bundled with Update 2 is not 2013 SP1.
I had to install SharePoint foundation 2013 SP1 before running the TFS installer