# TFS 2013 SharePoint Extensions cannot be installed on Windows 2012 R2

Tags: tfs

Share point and TFS server (on Win 2012 R2) are installed on different systems. How do we configure extensions for SharePoint Products through TFS 2013 update 4? Every time I get an error:

> SharePoint Foundation 2013 cannot be installed on Windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more information on formatting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SharePoint Foundation 2013 cannot be installed on Windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012 R2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738919/sharepoint-foundation-2013-cannot-be-installed-on-windows-8-1-or-windows-server)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should install SharePoint Extension on the SharePoint server machine, not on TFS server machine.

Secondly, I think it worth for you to take a look at of this case: [SharePoint Foundation 2013 cannot be installed on Windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012 R2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738919/sharepoint-foundation-2013-cannot-be-installed-on-windows-8-1-or-windows-server)

So, you can try to install [SharePoint Foundation 2013 with SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42039) or TFS2013 Update 2 first, then run the TFS installer.

Comment: TFS 2013 Update 4 is installed.